# How to read input into the array of strings where no string is longer than 4 characters?

Tags: c++, string, io, formatted-input

How would one go ahead and write parts of a string inside a for-loop? Let's say I have this code:

```
string str[64];
for( int i = 0; i < 64; i = i + 4 )
{
    cin >> str[i];
}
```

Everytime it enters the loop, I want to write four elements of the string. How would I go ahead and to that, since the code I wrote does not work? :P

Thanks :)

Comment: what do you mean by "writing parts of a string"? Are you looking for `std::string::substr()`?

Comment: @H2CO3 Let's say I have a string "Snoopdooog". Then one part might be Snoop and another part might be dooog. And I'm fairly new to using strings so maybe I am looking for that, maybe not.

Comment: your question is ambiguous. please, try to rephrase or give some additional examples.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
for( int i = 0; i < 64; i = i + 4 )
{
     for( int j = i; j < i + 4; j++ )
        cin >> str[j];
}
```

Comment: Ok I tried this and it didn't work as I wanted it to. I enter the loop, and write the first four letters of my string, let's say they are abcd. Then it goes through the loop again and I write another four letters; efgh. My string should now be abcdefgh, but it's only abcd. The efgh I wrote didn't get put into the string as well. I probably didn't explain it well enough, but that's what I wanted. :)

Comment: Do you want to concatenate two strings?

Comment: I tried this method to avoid using several strings. The thing is that with this program, I don't know how many strings I'll need, it could be any number from 1 to 16. That's why I decided to make one string that could contain up to 16 parts of four letters/digits, and then I could check for four letters at a time in another for-loop. I don't know how to make several strings depending on an input number. The best would be to create a new string every time in the for-loop and give it 4 letters/digits.

Comment: Could one make like an array of strings? Then I could just use a for-loop and use `cin >> str[i]`. That would be the best option for my program really.

Comment: Yes you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

```
std::string str[64];
```

declares an array of 64 `std::string` objects. If you'd like to read from the standard input character by character and fill this array with strings of maximum length 4, then it could look like this:

```
char c;
for (int i = 0, j = 0; std::cin >> c && i < 64; ++j) {
    str[i].push_back(c);
    if (j == 3) {
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

However also consider to do the opposite thing:

1. read "long" string at once *(if your input is within a single line, use `std::getline`)*
2. use `std::string::substr` to tokenize this string into small strings of length 4

   - and if you need to hold these tokens in memory, use `std::vector` instead of an array

i.e. :

```
std::string line;
if (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    size_t lineLen = line.length();
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;

    for (int i = 0; i < lineLen; i = i + 4)
        tokens.push_back(line.substr(i,4));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << tokens[i] << ", ";
}
```

You might also consider calling `tokens.reserve(len/4 + 1);` after the `tokens` vector is constructed to prevent redundant memory reallocations. And don't forget to `#include <vector>`.

Comment: I actually solved it on my own by using a char variable instead of strings. I'm too much of a newbie to understand anything you just wrote, but thanks a lot for trying to help anyways :)